# How to populate a choice field with all document library names site-wide

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, csom, jsom

I am trying to create a dynamic form that has a choice field which will have all the document library names in the site. It should be dynamic -- when I create a new document library, it should appear as a choice.

How can I accomplish this?

Answer (score 1):

You could create a list to store the all document library names in SharePoint online site.

Then you could create a lookup column to look up the field which stores the document library names.

And create a remote event receiver to add an item into the list when the document library is created.

More references:

Handling Events in a SharePoint Online Environment.

https://www.sharepointeurope.com/handling-events-in-a-sharepoint-online-environment/

SPRemoteEventType enumeration.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.remoteapp.spremoteeventtype.aspx

Comment: If the reply is helpful to you, you could mark the reply as the answer. Thanks for your understanding.